# read binary file into a 2d array matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binary

I use this code fragment to read a binary file into a array

```
 fid=fopen('data.bin','rb') % opens the file for reading
 A = fread(fid, count, 'int16') % reads _count_ elements and stores them in A
```

But it reads the file into a 1 dimensional array. Is there a direct method to read a binary file into a 2d array without me having to write loops to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
fid = fopen('data.bin','rb');
A = fread(fid, [rows columns], 'int16')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must know beforehand the number of rows/columns of the matrix you want to read. This way you read the values as an array, then reshape the result into the expected size:

```
A = reshape(A,[r c]);
```

Comment: my 1 D array length is 11139. How can i make use of reshape function. when i try to do B = reshape(A,100,111) i get a error  Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.  I cant even do a reshape(A,100,111.39) nor a reshape(A,100,112).

Comment: the problem is, as Amro said, that you need to know the expected rows/colums... if you're expecting 11100 elements, and you are reading more, then the problem comes from the way you read the file